# Knockout product filtering

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to create a product filtering system using Knockout. I will be receiving separate JSON files - one containing the products (and all associated properties) and a separate file for each individual filter. I need to display all results on page load, and then use the filter checkboxes to filter out the other options. I've set up a basic fiddle to replicate my structure at: http://jsfiddle.net/nimaek/0kbmchxe/4/ - in the real version, each object will be provided from JSON.

I've looked at a few tutorials and I think ko.utils.arrayfilter could be the solution I need - was also thinking the best method might be to include a filtering function in my object, like the below. But both of these ideas could be incorrect.

```
var colorFilters = [
    {id:"1", color: "white", filter: function(product){return product.color == "white";}},
    {id:"2", color: "black", filter: function(product){return product.color == "black";}},
    {id:"3", color: "blue", filter: function(product){return product.color == "blue";}}
];
```

What is the best method to use to get this functionality working? Needless to say, I'm just getting my head around Knockout, and although some of the examples I've found online look great, struggling to work out how to replicate these into my own project.

Thanks.

**Update**
Just to illustrate my question a bit more, I've replicated the functionality I'm looking for using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/nimaek/0kbmchxe/6/ - is there a better/more performant way to handle this using Knockout?

Comment: to be precise you need to do this way check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/0kbmchxe/9/ . hope that helps let us know any issues further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering is best done using computeds.

```
var colorFilters = ['white','black','blue'];
this.allColors = ko.observableArray(colorFilters);
this.selectedColors = ko.observableArray();
this.filteredProducts = ko.computed(function () {
    var self = this;
    if (self.selectedColors().length == 0) return this.allProducts();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.allProducts(), function (product) {
        return self.selectedColors().indexOf(product.color) >= 0;
    }, this);
}, this);
```

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kbmchxe/8/) with the color filtering, and have left the price filtering as an exercise for you. :)

Comment: ooh i see . my bad i see it now . i take back my comment :D .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the 'best' approach, but if you can have filter functions in your filter objects, then you can do something like this.

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var products = [
        {title:"Product 1", price: 100, color: "white"},
        {title:"Product 2", price: 200, color: "black"},
        {title:"Product 3", price: 200, color: "blue"},
        {title:"Product 4", price: 400, color: "white"},
        {title:"Product 5", price: 400, color: "blue"}
    ];
    self.allProducts = ko.observableArray(products);
    self.filteredProducts = ko.observableArray(products);

   var colorFilters = [
    {id:"1", color: "white", filter: function(product){return product.color == "white";}},
    {id:"2", color: "black", filter: function(product){return product.color == "black";}},
    {id:"3", color: "blue", filter: function(product){return product.color == "blue";}}
];
    self.allColors = ko.observableArray(colorFilters);

    var priceFilters = [
        {id:"1", price: 100,filter: function(product){return product.price == 100;}},
        {id:"2", price: 200,filter: function(product){return product.price == 200;}},
        {id:"3", price: 400,filter: function(product){return product.price == 400;}}
    ];
    self.allPrices = ko.observableArray(priceFilters);

    self.selectedFilters = ko.observableArray();
    self.addFilter = function(filter){

        if(self.selectedFilters.indexOf(filter)==-1)
            self.selectedFilters.push(filter);
        else self.selectedFilters.remove(filter);

        updateProducts();
        return true;
    };

    function updateProducts(){
     var p = [];
        if(self.selectedFilters().length==0)
            return self.filteredProducts(self.allProducts());

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.allProducts(), function(product){
            //apply filters
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedFilters(), function(filter){
                if(filter.filter(product) && p.indexOf(product)==-1)
                    p.push(product);
            });
        });
        self.filteredProducts(p);
    }

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/4722mLch/ (Shows products with any filter)

**UPDATE**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/4722mLch/2/ (Shows products matching both `price` **AND** `color` filters)

Comment: if you select `white` & `100` it should only display `product1` but its displaying `product4` too which is incorrect i believe .

Comment: @supercool you are probably right. This will show products that have 'any'  of filters applicable to them. So white/100 combination will show products that are either white **OR** priced 100.